# Is there a necessity to have locking / thread sync in libuv loop contexts running in different threads

Tags: multithreading, libuv

I want to spin up multiple threads with pthread and in each thread I wanted to start an async event loop, here in, libuv, using uv_loop_init() and wanted to poll for sockets and run few timers.

A sample program of time seems to crash at different places, and seems thread syncs is the reason.

So I just wanted to know if there are synchronisations needed even if there is loop created in each of the threads.

Also, I don't want to use threading of libuv itself, but wanted to start a thread and run a loop per thread.

Comment: Libuv can be used together with threads. Show us your code, you have an issue there. Also use threading of libuv, what is the point of avoiding it?

Comment: I'll get back to you with a sample code, soon. I wanted to run a thread per namespaces and open sockets from there. This will avoid calling set_ns() over and over again to open new sockets. So if I can start a thread set namespace for it, start a poller and open and close sockets. 

I was under the assumption that I can't do the same using uv's thread. Correct me if I am wrong here.